# MVC 4 Make form readonly based on ID of model

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I am using MVC 4.  I have a form that has several fields (I'm only going to show a couple fields to keep the post short).  Basically a user fills out this form and once the form is submitted, it can only be edited until management approves/rejects the submission.

The managementApprovalId is `NULL` by default, and as long as that Id is `NULL`, then edits can be made to the form.  Otherwise no edits can be made.

Should I have two separate views and in the controller render the editable view if the `managementApprovalId` is NULL and the uneditable view if it has a value that is not `NULL`?

Another option I thought of was creating an `htmlHelper` and in that `helper` add `readonly=readonly` if `managementApprovalId` is not `NULL`.

It would look something like:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.RequestTitle, WorkOrderHelper.IsEditable(workOrder))
```

Pseudo-code for helper:

```
public static Dictionary<string, object> IsEditable(WorkOrder workOrder)
{
    Dictionary<string, object> htmlAttributes = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    if (managementApprovalID != null)
        htmlAttributes.Add("readonly", "readonly");

    return htmlAttributes;
}
```

Any other suggestions on what to do?  The form is pretty big and I'm not sure adding an html helper to every field is the best way to do this?

Comment: something I have done in the past is to just disable the submit button.  Easier than trying to change all of the fields on a form to read only.

Comment: I like that idea, I think it could work.